# How to export all Sharing Setting Name, Rule Criteria and User/Group Shared with value in an Org

Tags: sharing

How to take export entire Sharing Setting Name, Rule Criteria and User/Group Shared-with value in an Org in csv/excel. 
Step by step process explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing rules are metadata and can be fetched using the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharingrules.htm?search_text=sharing). You can see examples of what it looks like here.

- So, if your application is Apex, you will need to use the [Apex Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)
- If your application is third party, then use the native [SOAP or REST Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm?search_text=sharing)

Converting this to a CSV form is beyond the scope of this answer so, if your solution is apex-based; give it a whirl and if you run into issues dealing with the Metadata API data structure and converting to CSV, post your code using **Edit**